# php class cannot set public static var

Tags: php, static

I'm having difficulty setting a public var in a class:

```
function printCaptcha($formId = NULL, $type = NULL, $fieldName = NULL) {
    require_once(SITE_ROOT . '/visualCaptcha/inc/visualcaptcha.class.php');
    $visualCaptcha = new \visualCaptcha\Captcha($formId, $type, $fieldName);
    $visualCaptcha->imageFile = BASE_URL . "image.php";
    $visualCaptcha->show();
}
```

`$imageFile` is the one I'm trying to set. The rest works fine.

Inside class:

```
public static $imagesPath = 'images/visualcaptcha/';
    public static $audiosPath = 'audio/visualcaptcha/';
    public static $imageFile = 'image.php';
    public static $audioFile = 'audio.php';
```

Full code of the class: https://github.com/emotionLoop/visualCaptcha-PHP/blob/master/inc/visualcaptcha.class.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it statically

```
\visualCaptcha\Captcha::$imageFile = BASE_URL . "image.php";
```

See http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.static.php#example-194

As of PHP 5.3, you can also use your class instance variable

```
$visualCaptcha::$imageFile = BASE_URL . "image.php";
```

though to me, this is confusing and ugly.

Comment: Wait, first 1, how do I put that in my code? directly like that? without variable in front?

Comment: @salivan Yup, exactly like that

Comment: Thanks for the link btw. I have start learning about classes in php.

Comment: I didn't know you could access class members through the instance variable.  Agreed on confusing a little worrying in fact,  smells wrong.

Comment: @Gavin It's *new* (well, 5.3 which is hardly new), just like `goto` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are bound to the class. Not the object.

Therefor you have to access it via the static context:

```
\visualCaptcha\Captcha::$imageFile = BASE_URL . "image.php";
```

(You can, if you want to use "the object" for that, use `get_class()` to get the classname for an object and call it then this way: `$classname::$var`)

However maybe you might want read on when to use static variables and when "normal" class and objects members.

Comment: +1 Correct answer.  The down vote likely came from the religious oop crew. You used the word static and didn't suggest the use of a DiC.  Thank goodness you didnt use "New" the backlash would have been huge :)

Comment: @Gavin The downvote was probably because the original answer had `::imageFile` instead of `::$imageFile`. FYI there is no downvote now